# RAM specs - clarification

Tags: memory

This is a quote from the specification of my mother board:

> Support for DDR4 2133 MHz memory modules

Does this mean that the maximum speed possible for the RAM is 2133 MHz?

Or can I put more (like 2400 MHz)?

What does that speed *actually* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as driving a street that has a speed limit. Can you use a car on that street that could go faster than the speed limit? Sure.
You can even *drive* that car faster than the limit - speeding is like overclocking; it has its risks.

Answer (score 0):

The `frequency` in RAM means how many bits have being transferred in a single second through a dataline. So more MHz means more faster the RAM.
Because your motherboard is said  to support 2133MHz RAM modules, it will bring down the speed of your RAM to 2133MHz if it is above the motherboard limit, and yes the RAM will work.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I'm talking about the MOBO's specs. Not the RAM themselves.

Comment: Oh! I misread it

Comment: Edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Many motherboard manufactures will state a general specification. This naturally has ambiguity, and rightfully so, as the frequency of RAM on the market will increase in speed as technological refinement by manufactures occurs.

If you were to place a PC4-17000 (2133 MHz DDR4) stick into the machine, it will work, it "supports" it. Will the motherboard accept higher frequency or "faster" memory? Will it support lower frequency or "slower" memory? In modern computers, this is likely to be true in both cases. There is no way to know this for sure, unless you consult your motherboard manufacturer or an approved/tested memory list they have published.

The chipset (ex. H77) can also be an important factor as to if the motherboard will accept faster/different sticks of RAM. You can use this to have some reasonable estimate as to the support available on your motherboard.